# Multiply exectuion, jobs and WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, handle

everyone!

I have some issue, which I don't know how to solve:

1. When I sent the value to function by pointer, `TerminateJobObject` doesn't work.
2. I don't know, how to kill not all job, only selected.

There is my code:

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

bool ExecuteSoftware(HANDLE * hSoftwareJob, char * name, const int countExecute);
void KillProcess(HANDLE hSoftwareJob);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE_CALC = 3, SIZE_PAINT = 1, SIZE_PAD = 2;
    HANDLE calcJob, paintJob, padJob;
    cout << "Execute calculator\n";
    if (!ExecuteSoftware(&calcJob, "calc.exe", SIZE_CALC))
    {
        cout << "Can't execute all process\n";
        Sleep(1500);
    }
    cout << "Execute paint\n";
    if(!ExecuteSoftware(&paintJob, "mspaint.exe", SIZE_PAINT))
    {
        cout << "Can't execute all process\n";
        Sleep(1500);
    }
    cout << "Execute WordPad\n";
    if(!ExecuteSoftware(&padJob, "write.exe", SIZE_PAD))
    {
        cout << "Can't execute all process\n";
        Sleep(1500);
    }

    Sleep(5000);

    cout << "Killing groups\n";

    KillProcess(calcJob);
    KillProcess(paintJob);
    KillProcess(padJob);
    TerminateProcess(calcJob, 0);

    /*for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        hJob[i] = CreateJobObject(NULL, (LPCSTR)L"calcJob");
    }
    HANDLE jobCalc = CreateJobObject(NULL, (LPCSTR)L"calcJob");
    PROCESS_INFORMATION* calcs = new PROCESS_INFORMATION[SIZE_CALC];
    JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION jInfo;


    ExecuteCalc(SIZE_CALC);
    Sleep(5000);
    KillProcess();*/
    Sleep(2500);

    return 0;
}

bool ExecuteSoftware(HANDLE * hSoftwareJob, char * name, const int countExecute)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    LPTSTR lpszSystemInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    TCHAR tchBuff[MAX_PATH + 1];

    lpszSystemInfo = tchBuff;
    GetSystemDirectory(lpszSystemInfo, MAX_PATH + 1);
    wsprintf(tchBuff, "%s\\%s", lpszSystemInfo, name);

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    for (int i = 0; i < countExecute; i++)
    {
        if (!CreateProcess(NULL, tchBuff, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            AssignProcessToJobObject(hSoftwareJob, pi.hProcess);
            Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    return true;
}


void KillProcess(HANDLE hSoftwareJob)
{
    TerminateJobObject(hSoftwareJob, 0);
}
```

My task:
`Launch of any number of programs and their selective or group termination`

Sorry for my English.

Comment: let ask for example - `AssignProcessToJobObject(hSoftwareJob, pi.hProcess);` what you do here ?

Comment: You have `HANDLE* hSoftwareJob` as an in/out parameter, in the `ExecuteSoftware` function you never actually create a job object, or initialise the handle or pass its value back out, and so it remains uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

First, as stated in the comment, you are short of initialization.

```
HANDLE notepadJob = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);
```

Second, you should pass the value pointed to by the `hSoftwareJobto` to `assignprocesstojobobject`.

```
AssignProcessToJobObject(*hSoftwareJob, pi.hProcess);
```

Third, from [AssignProcessToJobObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-assignprocesstojobobject#requirements) doc, it said that **desktop apps only**.

> A desktop application in C++ is a native application that can access
>   the full set of Windows APIs and either runs in a window or in the
>   system console. Desktop applications in C++ can run on Windows XP
>   through Windows 10 (although Windows XP is no longer officially
>   supported and there are many Windows APIs that have been introduced
>   since then).
>
> A desktop application is distinct from a Universal Windows Platform
>   (UWP) app, which can run on PCs running Windows 10, and also on XBox,
>   Windows Phone, Surface Hub, and other devices.

Refer: [Desktop Applications (Visual C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/desktop-applications-visual-cpp?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019)

For example, [calculator](https://github.com/microsoft/calculator#calculator) is a typical UWP app, so it cannot be used with `AssignProcessToJobObject`.

Modified Code : ( Notepad is used for test)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

bool ExecuteSoftware(HANDLE * hSoftwareJob, char * name, const int countExecute);
void KillProcess(HANDLE hSoftwareJob);
int main()
{
    HANDLE notepadJob;
    const int SIZE_NOTE = 3;
    notepadJob = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);

    cout << "Execute WordPad\n";
    if (!ExecuteSoftware(&notepadJob, const_cast<char*>("notepad.exe"), SIZE_NOTE))
    {
        cout << "Can't execute all process\n";
        Sleep(1500);
    }



    cout << "Killing groups\n";

    KillProcess(notepadJob);


    Sleep(2500);

    return 0;
}

bool ExecuteSoftware(HANDLE * hSoftwareJob, char * name, const int countExecute)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    LPTSTR lpszSystemInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    TCHAR tchBuff[MAX_PATH + 1];

    lpszSystemInfo = tchBuff;
    GetSystemDirectory(lpszSystemInfo, MAX_PATH + 1);
    wsprintf(tchBuff, "%s\\%s", lpszSystemInfo, name);

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    for (int i = 0; i < countExecute; i++)
    {
        if (!CreateProcess(NULL, tchBuff, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            AssignProcessToJobObject(*hSoftwareJob, pi.hProcess);
            int err = GetLastError();
        }
    }

    return true;
}


void KillProcess(HANDLE hSoftwareJob)
{
    TerminateJobObject(hSoftwareJob, 0);
    int err = GetLastError();
}
```